# Floating point exception (core dumped) while creating a C program for Linux

Tags: c, exception, coredump

I am new to C and need some help, when I execute this code, the output shows "Floating point exception (core dumped)" instead of a number which I don't know what it could be. I don't really know what is wrong with my code since I am a total beginner with Linux and C. Every help is appreciated.

Here is my functions.c:

```
#include "header.h"

int count(FILE *file){
    int count=0,n; 
    char word[WORDS];
    while(fscanf(file,"%s",word)==1 ){ 
        count++;
    };
    return count;
};

int total(FILE *file){ 
    int numbers, sum=0;
    int token;
    while(token!=EOF){ 
        token=fscanf(file,"%d",&numbers);
        sum+=numbers;
    };
    return sum;
};
```

and here is my main.c:

```
#include "header.h"

int main(){
    char word[WORDS];
    char theFile[WORDS]; 
    FILE *fileptr;
    printf("Enter the file name: ");
    scanf("%s",theFile); 

    printf("Reading file %s...\n", theFile);
    fileptr=fopen(theFile,"r");

    if(fileptr==NULL){ 
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: The file '%s' does not exist\n", theFile);
        return 1;
    };

    int theSum=total(fileptr); 
    int theCount=count(fileptr); 
    int theMean= theSum/theCount; 

    printf("Average weight: %d \n", theMean);

    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for getting Floating point exception is that you are accessing the file beyond its size.

In function `total` and `count` you are using the same pointer, so when done with `total` the file pointer is at the end of file, and you are using the same in `count` also.

you need to do `fseek(file,SEEK_SET,0);`, to make the pointer point at the beginning.

and all of you block statements and functions are end by `;`, thats wrong.

I have corrected the program as a whole assuming that the contents of the file are just numbers like this `1 2 3 4 5 6`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WORDS 100

int count(FILE *file){
    int count = 0,n; 
    char word[WORDS];
    // you need this to access the elements from start of the file
    // comment below line causes sigfpe, Floating point exception
    fseek(file,SEEK_SET,0);
    printf(" position of fptr in count = %d\n",ftell(file));
    while(fscanf(file,"%s",word)==1 ){ 
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int total( FILE *file ){ 
    int numbers, sum = 0;
    int token;
    // This is checked after number is read, will add the last number 2 times 
    //while(token != EOF){ 
    while(1)
    {
        token = fscanf(file,"%d",&numbers);
        printf("N = %d, token = %d\n", numbers, token);
        if(token == EOF )
            break;
        sum += numbers;
    }
    printf(" position of fptr in total  at the end = %d, sum = %d\n",ftell(file), sum);
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    char word[WORDS];
    char theFile[WORDS]; 
    FILE *fileptr;
    printf("Enter the file name: ");
    scanf("%s",theFile); 

    printf("Reading file %s...\n", theFile);
    fileptr=fopen(theFile,"r");

    if(fileptr == NULL){ 
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: The file '%s' does not exist\n", theFile);
        return 1;
    }

    int theSum = total(fileptr); 
    int theCount = count(fileptr); 
    //make sure to add a check that `theCount` is not zero
    int theMean = theSum/theCount; 

    printf("Average weight: %d \n", theMean);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```c
int theMean= theSum/theCount;
```

when `theCount` is 0 you are dividing by zero, which is undefined behavior and is probably causing the FPE.